# What are the differences between the map methods in ES6 and lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Can one do more than the other? Should I stick with lodash or just use ES6's map method?

Comment: I assume that by the ES6 map you mean the old one available on arrays. The answer is that there is almost no difference. Lodash has its `map` which is pretty much a straight replacement of the browser one. Useful for backwards compatibility. Other than that...one you call directly on an array, the other you call through lodash. Lodash can also map few more things like iterate over objects.

Comment: So lodash can map over objects? Thats nice to know.

Comment: Yes, although `_.map(obj, func)` will map over the _values_ and return an array, There is a separate `_.mapObject` that produces an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're both compliant with the ECMA-262 spec, so they're identical. However, for portability (and perhaps performance/readability), I personally prefer the built-in ES6 map method.

Comment: No, they are not identical. `_.map` can do far more than the stock `map`.

Comment: @georg please elaborate

Comment: @matanso you can use lodash shorthands, for example if you have an array of people that look like `{name: "bob", age: 42}` you can do `_.map(people, 'name')`  which is a shorthand for `_.property('name')` and you will be left with just the names of people.

Comment: @georg, you better write an answer for it.

Answer (score 10):

Besides [@georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg)'s comment on the possibility of using lodash `_.map` as a shorthand for `_.property`, lodash map can be used for any iteratable, whereas ES6 map can only be used for arrays.

Answer (score 7):

lodash can handle undefined

```
let a = undefined

_.map(a, (e) => {console.log("hello")})
// vs    
a.map((e) => {console.log('this is an error')}). //undefined error
```